# Google Analytics Pageviews differ from my own counter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I have a tracking code from Google Analytics im my website and a counter for every load of a View.

```
news.Views = news.Views + 1;
```

My counter for yesterday says 1185 Views for a News and Google Analytics says 526 Page Views for the same page.

I have the code in my _Layout:

```
<script>
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Should I place the tracking code in every View?

If not, so why the difference?

Comment: Google excludes non-javascript enabled user agents and people who have actively opted-out from tracking. That explains at least a part of the difference. Apart from that I don't think there's enough info here about your homegrown tracker to find the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks! What other information do you need?